# Are these two limits true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

Let $(a_n),(b_n)\subset\mathbb{C}$, be two sequences of  $\mathbb{C}$ such that 
$$\lim_{n\longrightarrow +\infty}|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2=|\lambda_1|^2+|\lambda_2|^2.$$

Is it true that
$$\lim_{n\longrightarrow +\infty}a_n=\lambda_1,\;\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow +\infty}b_n=\lambda_2??$$
Thank you.

Comment: if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2=10$ ,  what is $\lambda_1$ and what is $\lambda_2?$

Comment: $\sqrt{10}$ and $0$ for example

Comment: and why not 3 and 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is false in general. Consider $a_n=\cos(n\alpha)$ and $b_n=\sin(n\alpha)$.
Clearly
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow +\infty}|a_n|^2+|b_n|^2=1.$$
But neither $a_n$ nor $b_n$ has a limit.

Answer (score 3):

Why would it ? Just consider that

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow +\infty}a_n=\lambda_2,\;\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow +\infty}b_n=\lambda_1$$
is equally likely. (And there are other reasons why it doesn't hold.)